# Extending objects in array without redefining

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array of objects

```
var myArray = [{'id':'1','value':'firstValue'},{'id':'1','value':'secondValue'}, etc.]
```

I want to be able to extend the array later on in the code, so that I will have

```
var myArray = [{'id':'1','value':'firstValue', 'anothervalue':'anotherFirstValue'},{'id':'1','value':'secondValue', 'anothervalue':'anotherSecondValue'}, etc.]
```

Is there a way to do it without redefining myArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` the array, and add to each object:

```js
var myArray = [{
  'id': '1',
  'value': 'firstValue'
}, {
  'id': '1',
  'value': 'secondValue'
}];

//later on
myArray = myArray.map(function(obj) {
  obj.anothervalue = 'anotherFirstValue';
  return obj;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I will then have to change individually each value for the newly created set?

Comment: @Rockasaurus, depends on several things. You can often map other array data into a current array. Or, you can perform calculations in the map, and just add those to each value. Hopefully that makes sense.